# why I get the random output from the loop in c?

Tags: c, cs50

I try to solve the problem in pset2 of the CS50 lecture and when I run that code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <cs50.h>
# include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check if key is exists
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("%s", "usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // key
        string ciphertext = argv[1]; // "VCHRPZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI"
        int cipher_length = strlen(ciphertext);
        string msg_error = "\0";
        int x = 0;

        if (cipher_length == 26)
        {
            int msg_num = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ciphertext); i++)
            {
                if (isdigit(ciphertext[i]))
                {
                    msg_num = 0; // false
                }
                else
                {
                    msg_num = 1; // true
                }
            }
            if (msg_num == 1)
            {

                string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
                int n = strlen(plaintext);
                int a_letter = 'a';
                char plaintext_cp[n]; // copy from the original text
                char text[n];
                strcpy(plaintext_cp, plaintext);

                // to read the chars into plaintext
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    char lower_char = tolower(plaintext_cp[i]); // e.g -> d
                    if (lower_char >= 'a' && lower_char <= 'z')
                    {
                        int covert_to_ascii = lower_char; // 101
                        int index = covert_to_ascii - a_letter; // 101 - 98 = 4
                        if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                        {
                            text[i] = tolower(ciphertext[index]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            text[i] = toupper(ciphertext[index]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text[i] = lower_char;
                    }
                }
                printf("ciphertext: %s\n", text);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s\n", "key must only contain alphabetic characters.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", "Key must contain 26 characters.");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the output but also I get random output like this [screen-shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1kZp.png)

I tried to check the condition if ciphertext[i] is '\0' but I get the same issue.
 can anyone explain what is going on and How I can solve this problem?

Comment: `char plaintext_cp[n];` ==> `char plaintext_cp[n+1];` to include space for `'\0'`

Comment: `printf("usage...); return 1;` is incorrect.   If you want to print an error message and return non-zero, then you should write the message to stderr.   If you write a message to stdout then you are not treating the message as an error and you should return 0.  IOW, either do `fprintf(stderr ...); return 1;`, or `printf( ...); return 0;`.  IMO, a usage statement is not an error message, and you should choose the latter.

Comment: I try to understand what the point of n + 1 because n is 0 index so if I make it n + 1 I think it will ignore the first char so please can tell me why and how I do that? @pmg

Comment: Imagine your text is `"Hello"`. You then have `strlen(text) == 5` ... but the space required for the string is 6 bytes because `'\0'` must be counted for the copy too. So `char copy[strlen(text) + 1]; /* space for '\0' */ strcpy(copy, text);` --- also when you do `char foo[4];` the 4 elements are `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, and `foo[2]`, `foo[3]`.

Comment: ok now I understood this point but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you have provided, I do not think it is unintended output. The output comes out as should be, but, either while you were testing and CTRl+V'd into console, you did it too fast for the IDE and the string output followed behind it before going to a new line for a new input command; OR, it was just an accidental push onto the key and you haven't noticed. Otherwise it would have output that same (or if it is a flaw) another character every time you ran the command, but it seems to have only happened on the last command input.

(I have done this several times to myself when rushing or not paying attention)

The "printf" command under (// check if key exists) also has a %s (string pointer) but no string in the printf command, and isn't needed.

The last two printf's at the end of the file seem to have similar issues. The %s is not needed unless you have a string variable you plan on calling.